# Changing mirroring output of VR on display with greater FOV

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I have developed a Windows-based Unity application with VR and using the Meta Quest Pro headset (via Quest Link). Due to the (higher) resolution of the headset, the video of the headset is mirrored to the main screen of the computer, but with a much smaller Field of View, missing out on what the person is looking at.

I set up an additional camera that has target display set to 2, and this works but will only work if a 2nd monitor is connected. Can I either override the default output to display 1 (by the VR camera) and display my own additional camera on display 1? Or is there another way to either increase the FoV of the VR camera for how it is displayed on the main monitor of the computer?